# How to intercept abstract method

Tags: java, interceptor, cglib

Question title is not fully describes meaning of the question but I can't do it within title limitation. If you help me to change it to more convenient I'll be happy.

I have some class hierarchy described below:

AbstractParent :

```
public abstract class AbstractParent {

    public void realParentMethod() {
        System.out.println("invoking abstractMethod from realParentMethod");
        abstractMethod();
    }

    public abstract void abstractMethod();

}
```

ChildImpl:

```
public class ChildImpl extends AbstractParent {

    public void abstractMethod() {
        System.out.println("abstractMethod implementation is running!");
    }

}
```

I want to intercept **every** method invocation in this hierarchy and add some functionality. Even if method is invoked from each other I want to intercept each of them every time.

I use cglib Enhancer with MethodInterceptor implementation to do it:

```
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] srgs) {
    AbstractParent parentImpl = new ChildImpl();

    Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(AbstractParent.class);
    enhancer.setCallback(new LocalMethodInterceptor(parentImpl));

    AbstractParent proxyImpl = (AbstractParent) enhancer.create();
    // straight calling abstractMethod
    proxyImpl.abstractMethod();
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    // calling realParentMethod will lead to abstractMethod calling
    proxyImpl.realParentMethod();
    }

    static class LocalMethodInterceptor<T> implements MethodInterceptor {

        private T origin;

        public LocalMethodInterceptor(T origin) {
            this.origin = origin;
        }

        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
            try {
                System.out.println("intercept method["+method.getName()+"] before execution!");
                return method.invoke(origin, args);
            } finally {
                System.out.println("cleanup after  method["+method.getName()+"] execution!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the **problem** is that any method is intercepted only once:
If I invoke abstract method - It will be intercepted. But hierarchy was planned so way that you never have to invoke it (abstractMethod). You just invoke realParentMethod and it do all things for you, meaning it invokes abstractMethod from itself.

In this example if you call realParentMethod only realParentMethod will be intercepted, abstract method will be just skipped.

Here are some console output to this example:

```
intercept method[abstractMethod] before execution!
abstractMethod implementation is running!
cleanup after  method[abstractMethod] execution!
-----------------
intercept method[realParentMethod] before execution!
invoking abstractMethod from realParentMethod
abstractMethod implementation is running!
cleanup after  method[realParentMethod] execution!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of your delegation approach where you invoke the intercepted method on another instance `T origin`. Cglib creates a proxy where it overriddes any method to implement your `MethodInterceptor`. The interceptor is therefore only applied when it is invoked directly. One you pass to your `origin` object, the interceptor is therefore no longer in effect.

If you wanted to intercept any method call, instead of delegating, you would need to use the cglib object as a replacement for your delegation target. You can invoke the original method by invoking it via the `MethodProxy` instance.